# ionic: Map navigation not working in iOS 15

Tags: dictionary, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ios15

In our ionic app, we are using **@ionic-native/launch-navigator** plugin for navigate user to destination address in native map app.

Following navigation code is working fine for previous iOS versions, but not working for iOS 15.

Related code:

```
import { LaunchNavigator } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator';

constructor(
private navigator: LaunchNavigator
) { }

public navigate() {
this.navigator.navigate("London, UK")
}
```

in package.json:

"@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.36.0",
"uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.6"

Comment: i think you are are missing startPoint.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, if we have to navigate from current location to destination address without specific start location, then we can keep startPoint as optional right?

Comment: then you should pass your current `LatLng` as start point.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, the code without startpoint is working fine upto ios14 versions and even working fine in ios15 while debugging the application with Safari Technology Preview but not works in release mode.